# How to use CatJS to test Hybrid Mobile Application

Tags: cordova, unit-testing, jquery-mobile, automated-tests, ui-automation

I read about [CatJS](http://catjsteam.github.io/), a framework to do automation testing. From the tutorials and forums, I read that CatJs can be used to test Hybrid mobile Application build using jQuery Mobile.

I got jQuery mobile code snippet working in browser by reading [this](https://github.com/ransnir/catjs-jqm-seed#check-our-demo).

I want to know how to test this jQuery Mobile Appplication in Emulator as Application. I use Cordova to wrap the Application as Mobile Applications.

How to do Automation testing on Application runing in devices/emulators using CatJs.

I also read about [CatJsRunner](https://www.npmjs.org/package/catjsrunner) but I feel it is not clear or I cannot follow.

Thanks.